# Add subreport to grouped band

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I am currently stuck on a order-line sub-report that has grouping, based upon product-code so the data is sorted by JasperReports.

An order line can have multiple image attachments, which I would like to print inside the group as a subreport.

When I use a datasource expression, JasperReports throws an error as apparently this is not allowed, so how to proceed?

[image: more or less result wanted]

My files can be downloaded using this link an will probably self explain what I am trying to do.

[example files](https://miltenb.stackstorage.com/index.php/s/A5slUt0qFHgeyjV)

Comment: Your question is unclear. You should post the small *jrxml* to reproduce the problem. The posting of image will help you too

Comment: @AlexK : the example files are the smallest version of what I created ( without breaking it ( removed styles and all kinds of superfluous fields and data ).
Also added a picture of desired output.

Comment: Posting the JRXML file in this question will help others when, inevitably, the link to the examples expire.

Comment: @user3284253 `Multiple images should load here in a subreport` - What do you mean? Did you check your XPath? Is the results from XPath ok? What is an error you got?

Comment: How do I post the jrxml ? Should I post the code ( by pasting it into my previous post ?

@AlexK : I don't get any errors, but no data shows. I hard coded text into the subreport, that does not show. The Subreport works.

Comment: Yes, you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40178226/edit) post. Did you check the XPath? Did you check the input parameters?